# Deleting objects doesn't clear up space

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to clear up space on my computer so I decided to delete some objects in a blend file I have. After saving, I checked and the amount of space saved was pretty much nothing. Why isn't deleting the objects clearing up any space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem might be that you forgot to clear out the data in the file. Go to the outliner tab and select the display mode to orphan data. Remove anything in there that you don't need in your file. That should clear up space. This is normally done automatically, you must be using an older version.